# Как можно подключить уже имеющуюся таблицу (.sql) к файлу в pyhton и как обращаться к ней

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `geo` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `region_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lng` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `population` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8450 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

INSERT INTO `geo` (`id`, `country_en`, `region_en`, `city_en`, `country`, `region`, `city`, `lat`, `lng`, `population`) VALUES
    (1, 'United Arab Emirates', 'Ra\'s al Khaymah', 'Ras al-Khaimah', 'Объединенные Арабские Эмираты', 'Ras al Khaimah', 'Рас-эль-Хайма', '25.8006926', '55.9761994', 115949),
    (2, 'United Arab Emirates', 'Dubai', 'Dubai', 'Объединенные Арабские Эмираты', 'Дубай', 'Дубай', '25.2048493', '55.2707828', 1137347),
    (3, 'United Arab Emirates', 'Ash Shariqah', 'Sharjah', 'Объединенные Арабские Эмираты', 'Шарджа', 'Шарджа', '25.3223269', '55.5136433', 543733),
    (4, 'United Arab Emirates', 'Al Fujayrah', 'Al Fujayrah', 'Объединенные Арабские Эмираты', 'Фьюджейра', 'Фьюджейра', '25.4110762', '56.2482277', 62415),
    (5, 'United Arab Emirates', 'Abu Dhabi', 'Al Ain', 'Объединенные Арабские Эмираты', 'Абу-Даби', 'Эль-Айн', '24.1301619', '55.8023118', 408733),
    (6, 'United Arab Emirates', 'Ajman', 'Ajman', 'Объединенные Арабские Эмираты', 'Аджман', 'Аджман', '25.4052165', '55.5136433', 226172),
    (7, 'United Arab Emirates', 'Abu Dhabi', 'Abu Dhabi', 'Объединенные Арабские Эмираты', 'Абу-Даби', 'Абу-Даби', '24.2991738', '54.6972774', 603492),
    (8, 'Afghanistan', 'Takhar', 'Taloqan', 'Афганистан', 'Тахар', 'Талукан', '36.7338782', '69.5394189', 64256),
    (9, 'Afghanistan', 'Jowzjan', 'Shibirghan', 'Афганистан', 'Джаузджан', 'Шибарган', '36.6817149', '65.7490624', 55641),
    (10, 'Afghanistan', 'Sar-e Pol', 'Sar-e Pul', 'Афганистан', 'Сари-Пуль', 'Сари-Пуль', '35.6707473', '66.0463534', 52121),
    (11, 'Afghanistan', 'Wilayat-e Baghlan', 'Pul-e Khumri', 'Афганистан', 'Баглан', 'Баглан', '35.8042947', '69.2877535', 56369),
    (12, 'Afghanistan', 'Faryab', 'Maymana', 'Афганистан', 'Фарьяб', 'Меймене', '35.91784', '64.7755147', 75900),
    (13, 'Afghanistan', 'Balkh', 'Mazar-e Sharif', 'Афганистан', 'Балх', 'Мазари-Шариф', '36.6926167', '67.1179511', 303282),
    (14, 'Afghanistan', 'Kunduz', 'Kunduz', 'Афганистан', 'Кундуз', 'Кундуз', '36.7285907', '68.8680663', 161902),
    (15, 'Afghanistan', 'Khowst', 'Khost', 'Афганистан', 'Хост', 'Хост', '33.3338472', '69.9371673', 96123),
    (16, 'Afghanistan', 'Balkh', 'Khulm', 'Афганистан', 'Балх', 'Кем', '36.7027082', '67.7079491', 64933),
```

У меня есть таблица в файле с разрешением .sql Я пишу программу на python в которой требуется обращаться к строчкам из этой таблицы... я не понимаю как можно импортировать мою мини БД в файл .py

Comment: А как "таблица" выглядит внутри этого файла ?

Comment: Я прикрепил фрагмент таблицы

Comment: Вообще это не таблица, а исходный код для создания таблицы в БД MySQL. Вам надо установить MySQL, создать базу данных и запустить в ней этот файл, тогда он создаст таблицу а из питона вы уже будете работать с MySQL, о работе с БД MySQL множество статей есть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что у вас имеется, это не таблица, а ее "дамп". Как написали выше в коментарии, чтобы ее развернуть, вам необходима субд, в частности, MySQL.

#### Что для этого необходимо?

- установить субд MySQL на вашу операционную систему. Если у вас Windows, качаем дистрибутив [отсюда](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) и следуем инструкции по установке. Если linux, например, ubuntu, то устанавливаем через apt: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`
- после установки запускаем как службу (в Windows `net start [имя_службы]`, в linux - `service mysql start`).
- Далее необходимо создать базу данных, предварительно сделав настройку систему безопасности с помощью команды `sudo mysql_secure_installation` (ubuntu). Для создания БД я обычно использую mysql cli, который должен быть прописан в PATH: вводим в терминале `mysql-h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` и попадаем в командный интерфейс субд. Далее выполняем команду `CREATE DATABASE 'someapp' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf-8` (если это сложно, можете попробовать сделать то же самое с помощью **Workbench**).
- Затем, для взаимодействие с пайтоном, необходимо установить mysqlclient: `pip install mysqlclient`. Либо любой другой: [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL), MySQLdb, [mysql-connector](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python)... (желательно использовать виртуальное окружение)
- Загрузить дамп `mysql -u root -p someapp < dump.sql` через cli либо на пайтоне написать код для загрузки дампа с mysql. Ниже приведу пример с PyMySQL:

```py
import pymysql
 
def insert(title, date, text, textp):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',db='someapp',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            with open('dump.sql', 'r') as dump:
                sql = dump.read()
                cursor.execute(sql)
                connection.commit()
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

- Далее вы можете обращаться к созданной вами таблице. Собственно этот пункт и есть ответ на ваш вопрос, но до него все предыдущие пункты должны быть выполнены:

```py
import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'someapp')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM geo")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

#### PS:

Если инструкция по установке MySQL для вас оказалась не проста, можете скачать и установить OpenServer для Windows. Он автоматом установит вам все тулзы для MysqL

Comment: Вы уверены, что “cursor.execute(sql)” умеет обрабатывать сразу несколько SQL команд?? PS +1 за подробную инструкцию по установке MySQL)